# Why are my Git credentials stored when they aren't on another client?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I use the Git for Windows command line client (2.8.3) and notice that I do not have to enter my credentials when pushing to or cloning from our repository in Visual Studio Team Services.

I remember generating and using a one-time personal access token and since then I've not had to enter my credentials.

> A colleague of mine is asked for a username & password every time he interacts with the VSTS repo - he also used his own one-time access token but is still asked for a username and password each time.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I've also noticed that I'm not asked for credentials for my personal Github or Bitbucket repos - **I've not knowingly stored my credentials so I'm wondering why this is?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) installed, but your colleague does not. Or he has some configuration problems, see [Why am always prompted for my username and password?](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows#q-why-am-always-prompted-for-my-username-and-password).

There is a chance that he's using an outdated Git for Windows version that does not include the latest credential manager too, BTW.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've not knowingly installed Git Credential Manager & my colleague is using the same version Git client as me? (FYI we are both using the Windows client)

Comment: @VinylWarmth it's part of Git for Windows package and the option to install it can be unchecked on the initial install.